# How to get all Wordpress posts and display tags in Gatsby

Tags: wordpress, graphql, tags, gatsby

first time using Gatbsy and GraphQL. I am wondering how to display the tags. There are not listed in an obvious manner in the GraphQL editor.

I was hoping to find them under taxonomy but it is only displaying "Categories" and 'post' for name and types...

This is in a custom React page that will serve as a index for specific category posts.
Also, unrelated question... Gatbsy seems to only pull some of my content from the Wordpress site. I am missing a lot of the thumbnails despite the fact that they are featured images in the posts.

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allWordpressPage {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          excerpt
          slug
        }
      }
    }
    allWordpressPost {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          excerpt
          slug
          featured_media {
            source_url
          }
          categories {
            name
            taxonomy {
              name
              types

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const ClientProjectsIndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log({data})
  return (
    <div className="wave-pattern-bg">
      <VideoBanner
        text="Client Projects"
        videoSrc={meetingVid}
        imageSrc={null}
      />
      <Layout>
        <SEO title="Index of Client Projects" />
        <div className="card-wrap index">
          {data.allWordpressPost.edges
            .filter(post => post.node.categories[0].name === "Client Projects")
            .map((post, index) => (
              <Segment
                key={index}
                onClick={() => {
                  navigate(`/${post.node.slug}`)
                }}
              >
                <div className="index-portrait-wrap">
                  {post.node.featured_media ? (
                    <Image avatar src={post.node.featured_media.source_url} />
                  ) : (
                    <Image avatar src={emptyThumbnail} />
                  )}
                  <h1>{post.node.title}</h1>
                </div>
                <p>{post.node.excerpt}</p>
              </Segment>
            ))}
        </div>
      </Layout>
      <Contact />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ClientProjectsIndexPage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me, in my haste I seemed to have missed it!

I still have to figure out why most  of the featured images aren't being pulled but here is the tag query...

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allWordpressPage {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          excerpt
          slug
        }
      }
    }
    allWordpressPost {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          excerpt
          slug
          featured_media {
            source_url
          }
          categories {
            name
          }
          tags {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: I've made a bug request about the featured images issue. It may be a problem in the wordpress side of things but everything appears correct in the admin panel. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/23458